# systemd kill my processes before ExecStop completed

Tags: linux, admin, autostart, systemd

I'm trying to update my application to use it with systemd.
When I have used Upstart, I've just create a */etc/init.d/myService* script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#chkconfig: 2345 90 10
#description: myDescription

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: myService
# Required-Start: sshd
# Required-Stop: sshd
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start myService
# Description:
### END INIT INFO

SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)
lockfile="/var/lock/subsys/myService"

do_start() {
    if [ -d "/var/lock/subsys" ]; then
        touch $lockfile
    fi
    ...
}

do_stop() {
    ...
    if [ -d "/var/lock/subsys" ]; then
        if [ -f "$lockfile" ]; then
            rm -f $lockfile
        fi
    fi
}

do_status() {
    ...
}


case "$1" in
  start)
    do_start
    exit 0
    ;;
  stop)
    do_stop
    exit 0
    ;;
  status)
    do_status
    exit 0
    ;;
  restart)
    do_stop
    do_start
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

And all were fine.

**Notice**, this script generate some subprocesses which will executing in background.
To use it with systemd, I made the follow service file (*myService.service*):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Description
Requires=sshd.service
After=sshd.service
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myService start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/myService stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I run

```
systemctl stop myService.service
```

All work fine. My application stop successfully by */etc/init.d/myService stop* command.

But I've got the follow issue:
When I reboot the system, and */etc/init.d/myService stop* is executing, process which I should stop by *myService* script already killed. There are many processes which I should control ( around 7 processes ), and system should not terminated it itself.

I've tried to use Type=forking and specify the PIDFile as a pidfile of process, which has the longest life-time ( it should started first end stopped last ), however all my process were terminated again.

Is any simple way to avoid killing my subprocess?

Comment: You could start by picking a better StackExchange WWW site for non-programming questions, such as Unix & Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204922/

Comment: This is _not_ the proper way to create a systemd unit. You are specifically not meant to call your old-style init/upstart script. Do it correctly and you won't have any problems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have multiple servers setup with systemd service files making calls to init scripts.  I like this setup because it allows for a little bit of concurrency between my systemd and sysVinit servers while not relying on systemd to read LSB headers.

Could you please point out the reasoning as to why we "are specifically not meant to call" our init scripts?  Or perhaps some documentation?  Your statement completely contradicts the purpose and function of the systemd-sysv-generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found.

I ran hadoop & hbase, some of their components was starting by ssh-connection to localhost, and processes, which was started by this way, was unable to be controlled by systemd.
It was the design for distributed system, but in my case the work is going on the one machine. So I have replaced in *hadoop/bin/slaves.sh*

```
for slave in `cat "$HOSTLIST"|sed  "s/#.*$//;/^$/d"`; do
 ssh $HADOOP_SSH_OPTS $slave $"${@// /\\ }" \
   2>&1 | sed "s/^/$slave: /" &
 if [ "$HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP" != "" ]; then
   sleep $HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP
 fi
done
```

to

```
for slave in `cat "$HOSTLIST"|sed  "s/#.*$//;/^$/d"`; do
eval "$@"
 if [ "$HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP" != "" ]; then
   sleep $HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP
 fi
done
```

The problem was resolved and now processes are showing in service process tree.

Hbase probably has the same solution, but now it start with distributed=false and don't start any process by ssh.